# Anyone can help to fix this run time error?

Tags: java, runtime-error

Using arraylist and trying to get the last element, i am getting some runtime error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyProgram{

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public void printLastThing(){
        int lastIndex = list.size() - 1;
        String thing = list.get(lastIndex);
        System.out.println(thing);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyProgram example = new MyProgram();
        example.printLastThing();
    }
}
```

Comment: What runtime error?  You mean the one where printing the last element of an empty list fails?  What do you **expect** to happen in that case?

Comment: You haven't added anything to the list, so the size is 0. Therefore you're trying to get the element at -1, which causes the exception.

Answer (score 1):

There are no elements added to the list and so it is empty. YOu are trying to fetch the element at -1 which will raise java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException.

In this case you should keep a check for going out of bounds.

I have added a method to check the lastindex. It will return -1 if list is emtpy and you can display that List if empty once you get -1.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyProgram{

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public MyProgram() {
        list.add("a");
        list.add("z");
    }
    
    public void printLastThing(){
        
        int lastIndex = getLastIndex();
        if(lastIndex >= 0) 
            System.out.println(list.get(lastIndex));
        else
            System.out.println("List is empty");
        
    }
    
    private int getLastIndex() {
       if(list.size()==0) {
           return -1;
       }
       
       return list.size() - 1;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyProgram example = new MyProgram();
        example.printLastThing();
    }
}
```